# Express - Cannot retrieve api-key from request header

Tags: node.js, rest, express, fetch

I am working with Rest and `fetch()` API in browser to POST data with `x-api-key` header for authorization.
I tested the API with Postman and `curl` and it works just fine:

```
curl --header "X-API-KEY: my-api-key" -d "my-request-body" -X POST http://localhost:8081/submit
```

However, It doesn't work with the fetch api. On Chrome:

```
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    cache: 'no-cache',
    headers: {
      'x-api-key': 'my-api-key',
      'Accept': 'text/plain',
      'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    },
    redirect: 'follow',
    referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer',
    body: 'my-request-body'
  });
```

I'm not able the retrieve the API key from request. In my express, router handler:

```
router.post('/submit', cors(), async (req,res, next) => {
  const apiKey = req.header('x-api-key');
  console.log(apiKey) // THIS GIVES undefined
  });
```

**No `x-api-key` header is present in `req.headers` object either.** Kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. After struggling with it for a bit, I found the issue that was causing it...
The `mode: 'no-cors'` was causing it all along. Just set it to `mode: 'cors'` instead and you are good to go, for some reason

Answer (score 0):

I see an issue, not sure if that is what is causing it but you have forgotten your `,` in your fetch headers, maybe try after adding the `,`?

Comment: nope, that's not causing it. I edited the question